# What is wrong with my JavaScript? It won't compute and display the value I want it to; it's driving me bonkers!

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with my JavaScript?

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1 /DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

 ...

<body> 
   <p>
   <a href="http://nova.umuc.edu/~ct386a28/handson/index.html">Main Page</a>
</p>
<h1>GAS MILEAGE CALCULATOR</h1> 

<form action="" method="post">

<script type = "text/javascript">

 function mileageCalculator (beginMil, endMil, galCons, form)
 {

    var bM = parseFloat(beginMil);
    var eM = parseFloat(endMil);
    var gC = parseFloat(galCons);

    if((eM<0)||(bM<0)||(gC<0))
    {
        alert("ERROR: One or more input(s) is negative.");
        form.begMileage = " ";
        form.endMileage = " ";
        form.galConsumed = " ";   
    }

    else if ((eM == 0) || (gC == 0))
    {
        alert("ERROR: The end mileage and/or gallon input is zero.");
        form.begMileage = " ";
        form.endMileage = " ";
        form.galConsumed = " ";            
    }

    else if (eM < bM)
    {
        alert("ERROR: End mileage is less than begining mileage.");
        form.begMileage = " ";
        form.endMileage = " ";
        form.galConsumed = " ";
    }
    else 
    {                               
        form.mpg.value = ((bM - eM) / gC);  

    } 
 }

 </script>



    <div class = "center">              
        <h3>Enter beginning mileage:</h3>   
        <input type="text"  name ="begMileage" tabindex="1" />
        <br />
        <h3>Enter ending mileage:</h3>
        <input type="text" name ="endMileage" tabindex="2"  />
        <br />
        <h3>Enter gallons consumed:</h3>
        <input type="text" name ="galConsumed" tabindex="3" />
        <br />

        <h2>TOTAL MILES PER GALLON</h2>
        <input type="text" name ="mpg" tabindex="4" /> <br />

    </div>

    <p><br /></p>

    <p>         
     <br /><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick = "mileageCalculator"/> <input type="reset" value="CLEAR"/> <br />
    </p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just submit a form to a function. You will have to get the form field values using some DOM method and pass it into your function. And vice versa, you have to access the form field you want to output to and set the value.

Even though this is a bit out of date, this follows your pattern nicely.

http://www.javaworld.com/jw-06-1996/jw-06-javascript.html

Comment: Woooooooooooooooooooooow.  I am soooo special.  Fixed it (I am new to JavaScript :)  <br /><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick = "mileageCalculator(this.form.begMileage.value, this.form.endMileage.value,this.form.galConsumed.value, this.form)"/>

Comment: So any idea why when I calculate the mpg it only displays for a second then disappears?                                                      var total = ((eM - bM)/gC);
form.mpg.value = total.toFixed(2);

Comment: Because you are likely posting back to the page. You will have to return `false` from your function.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you need to either access your DOM elements in JavaScript or pass them into the function you are calling.  See this updated version of your code that achieves the result you are looking for: [Working Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/8h4qd/)

[Edit] As a note on style, it is generally considered good practice to not include your scripts within the middle of your HTML.  Most commonly, you will see it in `HEAD`.